# cannot call value of non-functional type 'DispatchQueue'

Tags: swift3, ios10

After converting to swift 3 i found got this error kindly someone let me know whats the solution for this cannot call value of non-functional type 'DispatchQueue'[image]

Thank You

Answer (score 3):

The error message means you call a function on a type where a property is expected.

Remove the parentheses after `main`

```
DispatchQueue.main.asynchronously(...
```

In the final release of **Swift 3** it's simply

```
DispatchQueue.main.async { .... }
```

Answer (score 2):

In `Swift 3` main is not a `function` anymore. It's a `class property`. So, you can access like this:

```
DispatchQueue.main.asynchronously(execute: { 
    //Here Goes your code
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
//Error : - In swift3 main is not a function

DispatchQueue.main().asynchronously(execute: {[weak self] in

                //.....
 })

//Solution :-

DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: { [weak self] in

                //....
 })
```

hope it helps.